# how to reset bootstrap progress bar to 0%

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a mental exercise type game ([add1.herokuapp.com](http://add1.herokuapp.com)) and there's a time limit for how long the player has left. I want to use the bootstrap progress bar to implement this, and I've basically achieved this effect by overriding the transition-duration property in the bootstrap CSS

*custom.css*

```
.progress-bar {
  -webkit-transition: width 5s linear;
       -o-transition: width 5s linear;
          transition: width 5s linear;
}
```

The problem comes when I want to set this progress bar back to zero (play the app to see this in action). The bootstrap progress bar does not go back to 0%, even though the width is being set to zero through angular data binding.

*game.html*

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{progressNum}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{progressNum}}%;">
    <span class="sr-only">{{progressNum}}% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

*game.js*

```
//When I call setTimer, I call this
$scope.progressNum = 100;

//When I want to reset for the next problem, I call this
$scope.progressNum = 0;
```

My guess is that even though the progressNum is changing, bootstrap does not reflect these changes. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **[angular-ui's bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)** progressbar directive, it has the facilities you need to control your progress bar's current value, maximum value and even the color.

**[See this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OLuDjxseYtY7d36h2gjj?p=preview)** I've made to demonstrate how to change the value of your progress bar. By clicking each **value** button below, triggers the ng-click handler that changes the value of the progress bar.

**JAVASCRIPT: **

```
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.progress = {
      value: 50,
      max: 100,
      color: 'warning'
    };

    $scope.changeValue = function(value) {
      $scope.progress.value = value;
    };

  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div progressbar 
    class="progress-striped active" 
    max="progress.max" 
    value="progress.value" 
    type="{{progress.color}}">

    <i>{{progress.value}}/{{progress.max}}</i>

</div>

<strong>Value: </strong><br>
<div class="btn btn-default" ng-click="changeValue(0)">0/100</div>
<div class="btn btn-default" ng-click="changeValue(25)">25/100</div>
<div class="btn btn-default" ng-click="changeValue(50)">50/100</div>
<div class="btn btn-default" ng-click="changeValue(75)">75/100</div>
<div class="btn btn-default" ng-click="changeValue(100)">100/100</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-style` to apply inline CSS conditionally.  I've created a plunkr to demonstrate how to use it with width.

http://plnkr.co/edit/t1UHAjjDHse7QBiKz64i?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="" ng-init="myStyle={width: '100px'}">
  <input ng-model="myStyle.width">
  <br/>
  <span style="background: red; display: block" ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
  <pre>myStyle={{myStyle}}</pre>
</body>
```